# creat a class for complex number, I got error 'TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) '

Tags: python, string, class, debugging, methods

as a beginner, I met the below problem, I created a class for complex number calculation. the problem is from the **str** method.  can you tell me the reason and how can I solve it? thank you!

import math

```
class Complex(object):
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real= real
        self.imaginary = imaginary

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.real + other.real, self.imaginary + other.imaginary)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.real - other.real, self.imaginary - other.imaginary)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.real*other.real-self.imaginary*other.imaginary,self.real*other.imaginary+self.imaginary*other.real)
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        r=(self.real*other.real+self.imaginary*other.imaginary)/(other.real**2+other.imaginary**2)
        img=(self.imaginary*other.real-self.real*other.imaginary)/(other.real**2+other.imaginary**2)
        return Complex(r,img)
    def mod(self):
        return Complex((self.real**2+self.imaginary**2)**0.5, 0)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.imaginary == 0:
            result = "%.2f+0.00i" % (self.real)
        elif self.real == 0:
            if self.imaginary >= 0:
                result = "0.00+%.2fi" % (self.imaginary)
            else:
                result = "0.00-%.2fi" % (abs(self.imaginary))
        elif self.imaginary > 0:
            result = "%.2f+%.2fi" % (self.real, self.imaginary)
        else:
            result = "%.2f-%.2fi" % (self.real, abs(self.imaginary))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = map(float, input().split())
    d = map(float, input().split())
    x = Complex(*c)
    y = Complex(*d)
    print(*map(str, [x+y, x-y, x*y, x/y, x.mod(), y.mod()]), sep='\n')
```

Comment: You never `return result` from your `__str__` method.

Comment: There's no need for the `result` variable. Just use a `return` statement to return the strings.

Comment: I have edit the code, because use other template is passed. when I use pycharm, it cannot pass

Comment: yes, Barmar, when I replce result with return it works in pycharm

Answer (score 1):

The `__str__()` method should return the strings, not assign them to a variable.

```
    def __str__(self):
        if self.imaginary == 0:
            return "%.2f+0.00i" % (self.real)
        elif self.real == 0:
            if self.imaginary >= 0:
                return "0.00+%.2fi" % (self.imaginary)
            else:
                return "0.00-%.2fi" % (abs(self.imaginary))
        elif self.imaginary > 0:
            return "%.2f+%.2fi" % (self.real, self.imaginary)
        else:
            return "%.2f-%.2fi" % (self.real, abs(self.imaginary))
```

Comment: I don't understand why it works in on that  online platform, the __str__ is their original code , I only add the calculation methods.

Comment: Maybe you didn't copy it correctly, and the original code ended with `return result`

Comment: you are right, you are programming master !